# Separate widgets in other files flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to make my code neater but I have a problem when I separate widgets that I use often in 1 file

here is it my main widget

```
import 'package:a_tiket/Helpers/widget_helper.dart';
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {    
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  bool _isLoading = false;
  var _message = '';
  var _hasError = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      _isLoading ?
      _loadingWidget(context)
          :
      Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
          )
      )
    ;
  }
}
```

this is my widget_helper.dart

```
Widget _loadingWidget (BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor: ACCENT_COLOR,
        valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(PRIMARY_COLOR),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

the problem is i got some error. i have add import for widget_helper but still get error

```
lib/Pages/loginPage.dart:193:7: Error: The method '_loadingWidget' isn't defined for the class '_LoginPageState'.
```

what should i do? i just want to make the code neater

Answer (score 12, accepted):

please remove `underline` 
change from

```
_loadingWidget(context)
```

to

```
loadingWidget(context)
```

Comment: underline means private not public

Comment: you can not see private

Comment: how can pass variable?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code:

- For such a small piece of code like showing a
  CircularProgressIndicator you should not be putting a method in a separate
  file. Instead of making your code "neater", you are making it harder
  to read. If you really want to have it in a separate file, create a Stateless widget that shows the code you want. But then again you are just using a CircularProgressIndicator. You aren't saving any code, just creating more unnecessary code.
- You already have a Scaffold where your are going to show the CircularProgressIndicator. You don't need to have another one. It's not doing anything.
- While Dart uses camelCase for variable naming, file names use snake_case. Try to use it when naming files.

Comment: I need to call isloading in everywhere. So, what should i do for neater code? As i remember CircularProgressIndicator from library